# Script not running in crontab, but runs fine in the bash terminal

Tags: linux, cron

I want to run a bash script in crontab, but crontab is not running it. I can run the script fine in the bash terminal.

I have read on this issue and tried all the options I could find, but nothing is working.

Can someone please help?

`crontab -l` (I have included the suggestions regarding SHELL and PATH and using absolute full path):

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
* * * * * /home/opc/testCron.sh
* * * * * /home/opc/startMyApp.sh
```

Now, the *really strange* thing is that `testCron.sh` runs from the cron, but `startMyApp.sh` **doesn't**.

testCron.sh is simple script I wrote to test cron (this script works).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running /home/opc/testCron.sh"
touch /home/opc/cron.test
```

startMyApp.sh is a slightly more complex script.

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(jps | grep MyApp| awk ' { print $1 } ')
echo "MyApp app PID: ${result}"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks